# How to avoid crash "OpenGL rendering while app in background state"

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, google-fabric

I got many crash reports recently on fabric. It says Based on the stack trace displayed here, it looks like new calls triggering OpenGL rendering took place while the app was transitioning to, or from, a background state. If you set up OpenGL drawing in your app delegate's methods, make sure that you only did so in applicationDidBecomeActive:, never in application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.

```
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib  gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient
1   AGXGLDriver (Missing)
2   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib  gpusSubmitDataBuffers
3   AGXGLDriver (Missing)
4   WebCore WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::reshape(int, int) + 580
5   WebCore WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::initializeNewContext() + 936
6   WebCore WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::WebGLRenderingContextBase(WebCore::CanvasBase&, WTF::Ref<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D> >&&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes) + 660
7   WebCore WebCore::WebGLRenderingContext::create(WebCore::CanvasBase&, WTF::Ref<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D> >&&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes) + 84
8   WebCore WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::create(WebCore::CanvasBase&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes&, WTF::String const&) + 1416
9   WebCore WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement::getContext(JSC::ExecState&, WTF::String const&, WTF::Vector<JSC::Strong<JSC::Unknown>, 0ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>&&) + 904
10  WebCore  WebCore::jsHTMLCanvasElementPrototypeFunctionGetContext(JSC::ExecState*) + 424
11  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 89612
12  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
13  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
14  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
15  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
16  JavaScriptCore  llint_entry + 82980
17  JavaScriptCore  vmEntryToJavaScript + 268
18  JavaScriptCore  JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 424
19  JavaScriptCore  JSC::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 200
20  WebCore  WebCore::JSExecState::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 140
21  WebCore  WebCore::ScheduledAction::executeFunctionInContext(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::JSValue, WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext&) + 424
22  WebCore  WebCore::ScheduledAction::execute(WebCore::Document&) + 144
23  WebCore  WebCore::DOMTimer::fired() + 816
24  WebCore  WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 216
25  WebCore  WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 28
26  CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
27  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
28  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
29  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1844
30  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
31  WebCore RunWebThread(void*) + 600
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body + 128
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start + 44
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start + 4
```

How to find where the code crashes?

Answer (score 2):

to my knowledge apple doesn't support openGL with iOS 13 or 10.15, try converting it to metal

"Important: OpenGL was deprecated in macOS 10.14. To create high-performance code on GPUs, use the Metal framework instead. See Metal."

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html

Comment: Ya, I didn't use openGL.

Answer (score 0):

GLKViewController is working perfectly in ios 13. As for your question, I did it in the following way.

In your app delegate.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@".applicationWillResignActive" object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@".applicationDidBecomeActive" object:nil];
}
```

Then in your rendering view controller.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
                                                     name:@".applicationWillResignActive"
                                                   object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)
                                                     name:@".applicationDidBecomeActive"
                                                   object:nil];
         self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30;
         self.pauseOnWillResignActive = NO;
         self.resumeOnDidBecomeActive = NO;
}
```

GLKit has its own mechanism for handling going to the background (that pauseOnWillResignActive property) but it did not work well for me. I suspect because it only stops rendering timer but does not flush the gl operations queue with glFinish() or glFlush(). So I handled it myself.

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@".applicationDidBecomeActive" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@".applicationWillResignActive" object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)note
{
        [self suspend];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)note
{
        [self resume];
}
```

And now your suspend and resume methods may look like this.

```
-(void) suspend
{
        self.suspended = YES;
        glFinish();
}

-(void) resume
{
        if (self.suspended) {
                self.suspended = NO;
                [(GLKView *)self.view display];
        }
}
```

PS. Though it works fine, this is quite an old API (GLKit). I really recommend you to figure out how to use metal.

Comment: I never used GLKViewController in my app. I just used a third library "Lottie".

Comment: Then as a minimum, you can intercept applicationWillResignActive() and issue glFinish() in it. If not working - check with your "Lottie" for its rendering cycle. It should have some kind of pause() and resume() as the most of apis have.